# In which folder of kentico application resource strings are stored

Tags: kentico

[In which folder these strings are stored in kentico](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xeyZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're stored in the DB itself in two tables:  `CMS_ResourceString` and `CMS_ResourceTranslation`.  You can find out more on the [Working with resource strings](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/multilingual-websites/setting-up-a-multilingual-user-interface/working-with-resource-strings) page in the documentation, which will also help if you need to think about `resx` files.

As you can see from the documentation, theDB is the default and the DB gets the highest priority.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your setup. The physical folder is CMSResources, but check [Working with resource strings](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/multilingual-websites/setting-up-a-multilingual-user-interface/working-with-resource-strings) . The system uses the priority when loading resource strings.  By default the rule is:

1. database (Localization application) – highest priority
2. site specific resx files
3. resx files of custom modules
4. custom.resx
5. cms.resx

So lets say if you resource string is defined in database (and it has the highest priority) the system takes it from there and ignore the same name resource string in cms.resx  for example.

If you want to get resource string that are stored in the DB you can the following query:

```
SELECT stringKey,  CultureCode, TranslationText 
        FROM CMS_ResourceString (NOLOCK)
        JOIN CMS_ResourceTranslation (NOLOCK) on TranslationStringId =  stringId
        JOIN CMS_Culture on  TranslationCultureID = CultureID
```